Why does VS-Code not compile my LaTeX-file with LaTeX-Workshop and macTeX installed?
I have installed macTeX (I use MacOS Sonoma 14.5) and LaTeX-Workshop in VS-Code. It seems like VS-Code is not recognizing my .tex-files. Every time I want to compile and generate a pdf I get an error message and after hours of research I still have not found the problem.
The error-messages I get are the following:
*Code language not supported or defined*

*Recipe terminated with error*

*[11:41:52.066][Build] Recipe returns with error code 12/null on PID 5700.
[11:41:52.066][Build] Does the executable exist? $PATH: /opt/anaconda3/bin:/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin, $Path: undefined, $SHELL: /bin/zsh
[11:41:52.066][Build] Latexmk: Sometimes, the -f option can be used to get latexmk
  to try to force complete processing.
  But normally, you will need to correct the file(s) that caused the
  error, and then rerun latexmk.
  In some cases, it is best to clean out generated files before rerunning
  latexmk after you've corrected the files.

[11:46:31.007][Structure][LaTeX] Error loading content during structuring: %WS1%/test.tex .
[11:51:50.977][Event] STRUCTURE_UPDATED
[11:51:51.272][Structure][LaTeX] Error loading content during structuring: %WS1%/test.tex .*

I have seen documentation that talks about "Setting PATH environment variable" but I have no clue on how to do that (if that is the problem) since the documentation on how to set this environment variable is really bad for someone who does not know much about this.
ChatGPT told me to change json-Code in the settings of VS-Code but that didn't work either.
